# Let's pick a new logo for Salesforce Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, design

2 things:

1) Salesforce loves this community. I know because I just got out of a lunch with Nick Tran and Domenique Sillett. We ate sloppy joes. They gush over you.

2) They tell us we have to kill THE cloud. We can use A cloud. Just not their specific sacred brandmark, which can only be used on official Salesforce products.

So let's gather some ideas, stick drawings, poetry, what have you, and see if we can come up with something new. One idea per answer please. I'll drag a designer in on this after we collect a few quality ideas.

Looking forward to seeing what you come up with.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer (or a paid spokesman =-P), but why not change the cloud's outline so that it doesn't mirror SalesForce's own cloud, and here's the lawyer part:  Since a cloud as a trademark isn't unique or novel, wouldn't using a cloud of our own design be acceptable under fair use?

Comment: ☁ There. Problem solved. They really should come up with a list of non-official "brands" that third-party people can use without permission.

Comment: Oh yeah - I wanted to mention:  Of course we don't want to make SF mad, but at the same time, the cloud is so closely coupled with SF in users' minds, it's more confusing to pick a new logo that doesn't include an image of a cloud.  It's a case of being a victim of your own success, e.g. Kleenex, google and Xerox

Comment: So is it allowed to use a cloud shape in the new logo or not?

Comment: @mast0r we can use A cloud. Just not THAT cloud, it turns out.

Comment: as this is `salesforce stack exchange', I'd vote for a "stack" of clouds

Comment: Or mirror image?

Answer (score 16):

I'm pretty sure the branding was determined by StackExchange in collaboration with Salesforce to begin with, and there were definitely interactions with the legal team about it.

That said, if they say it has to change, then I guess it has to change. Personally I think it should just be a different cloud shape, little else really makes sense unless it's based around "SFSE" as a term which has become the communtiy nickname for the site.

Comment: [This one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) looks a bit like the SFDC cloud.

Comment: A new cloud shape seems like the way to go. I'm going to poke a designer and see if we can get a couple options in front of you and pick one that you like.

Comment: I agree with Peters comments on his answer, if we can't use THE cloud, then I say we don't try to imitate it with some other knock off cloud.  Let's try to go in a new direction if we can't use the cloud

Comment: Agreed.  The shape of the cloud, specifically, is very recognizable.  To change it just to comply would be odd (unless we mirror-imaged it maybe?).  I wouldn't change the shape, I'd look for something new...

Answer (score 10):

It's a "cloud" they say? Hmm, interesting. In a "former life", I did graphic design. Below are some of the things I "saw" when looking at our logo. First, here's what our "Network" looks like without the "cloud" and just the "lines":

[image: Current SF.SE Logo Network Lines]

Doesn't have much impact does it? I didn't think so either, so added "small nodes" to the endpoints"

[image: Current SF.SE Logo Network Lines with nodes added]

This seemed like something of an improvement to me, but reminded me a lot of playing with tinker toys when I was a very young boy, 50 or so yrs ago.

What I particularly noticed when looking at "THE CLOUD" is that it's constructed using **CIRCLES**. So is it a "Cloud" or is it a collection of circles? If we change our existing logo to look like a collection of circles, would we be infringing on the "THE CLOUD"?

I think that would be a difficult case for SF to make. But that's just my opinion. Below is an example showing what I discovered using circles of different sizes and colors that could easily be reworked in countless ways, including removing the nodes and putting it back inside a contrasting rectangular box (will update post with example if I find time to create one):

[image: THE CLOUD as circles with our network and nodes]

Makes "THE CLOUD" look very different doesn't it?? I certainly think it does. it's clear to me that's how they designed it; as a collection of circles or "balloons". Perhaps we should take a pin and just pop one...

I said I'd do this, if I found the time, so here it is. Our current logo with "circles" behind it on a rectangular solid colored background. Are these circles the same as "THE CLOUD" or are they just colored circles? I'll let you be the judge...

[image: Current SF.SE network logo design on top of collection of circles with solid background]

And just for @Samuel De Rycke, a version with fewer lines & smaller nodes too! Hopefully, it's a bit less "dizzying". ;)

[image: Similar to existing logo, but with fewer lines]

Comment: I like the story, but am I the only one for who this is too much lines ? It makes me feel a little bit dizzy, no where to focus.

Comment: I don't disagree. That's how I felt about the design when it was initially released (the network portion of it). There's no reason it couldn't be simplified. I was simply trying to illustrate a point using what we currently have. Also, behind the cloud is a network, that's something I think we all understand.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke. Added one with fewer lines, just for you...

Answer (score 6):

I saw the note come through from the brand managers here at Salesforce so knew that this would happen soon. I know we worked with branding initially, but things can change. And I guess they did.

I will miss the cool cloud, though. I still have a sticker on my laptop that Dan Hoechst handed out at DF14.

I think some variation of the trailhead mountain might be cool...there is a little cloud above that.

There is also Astro...either in astronaut, raccoon, or race car driver form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So I got word back from the (your?) team, and it looks like we can use A cloud. Just not THE cloud. So I think that's probably the best option. I'll have the design team over here cook up a couple options.

Comment: I disagree...none of the other clouds out there look like the *Salesforce* cloud. Maybe I'm very sensitive to it working for a brand-conscious company. But any other cloud just doesn't say "Salesforce" to me. This is why I would like to just not use a cloud. "Cloud" as a term to define some kind of technology is over used, and has become blurred in its meaning. Just my $.02.

Comment: Is Astro a possibility? That could actually be pretty cool.

Comment: I agree with @Peter, if we can't use THE cloud, then using some other cloud, just seems silly as it will seem like a cheap knock off.  I say if we can't use THE cloud, then go in a different direction.  What that direction is......well, I'm not as much help there...

Comment: Is there something that suggests how SFSE is better than forums? :)

Comment: Raccoon Astro would get my vote, if we're not doing a cloud.

Comment: If we go with the astronaut, I would like it much better without the `1` on the flag. Maybe change it from `Salesforce1` to `SFSE` and it would get my vote. Hard to turn into a favicon though.

Comment: How is going with an astronaut that looks like Astro from trailhead any less of a copyright infringement than what Salesforce is trying to claim we're doing now with "THE CLOUD"? I just don't follow that logic.

Comment: If we could have a SFSE specific astro, that would totally rock, maybe the SF/Dev marketing team who's behind this logo may even be willing to help design one ?

Comment: I have just asked the Dev Marketing team to check into the Astro idea and pointed them to this meta question. @crmprogdev corporate marketing do not recognize Astro as an official brand or trademark. (Not yet anyway.)

Comment: @Peter, note what Astro's wearing on his chest. Isn't that "THE CLOUD"? Do you replace "Salesforce 1" on the flag with "StackExchange"? Not trying to be difficult, but just asking the obvious branding questions that are inherent to the image. I'd be surprised if it's not a copyrighted image. If it isn't, someone hasn't done their job and will get around to it eventually.

Answer (score 4):

I know of at least 2 other cloud providers who have a cloud in the logo.

[image: Micrsoft Azure]

[image: Amazon S3]

I am not sure what Salesforce means by the "cloud is sacred"!

Comment: I read their comment as: Not any cloud, but the cloud in SFDC's logo (http://www.sfdcstatic.com/common/assets/img/logo-company.png). There is no claim that Salesforce has a trademark on all forms of clouds.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate that you would ask our opinion, but I'm not sure how many quality ideas you'd be able to get out of this group. (There might be some talented artists here, it's just that I haven't seen many people here on the [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site).

One thing we could consider doing is having a [contest](http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774) for the logo design.

Answer (score 2):

ones and zeros in the cloud.

I like that because we constantly build in salesforce...  evolution is always happening.

Answer (score 2):

One concept I really like is using attractive colors to enthusiasm, transparency to show collaboration in a single cloud. Now a days eye-catching colors are in use a lot.

Logo should give a feel of:

- Energy
- Transparency
- Collaboration

---

Few of the designs which ca be referenced are:

Salesforce Platform Cloud:

[image]

another one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We should just use a different cloud. There are plenty out there, many free templates. Not a problem.