# A new logo for Salesforce Stack Exchange (revised version)

Tags: discussion, design

> See previously: [Let's pick a new logo for Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/lets-pick-a-new-logo-for-salesforce-stack-exchange)

Our designers rounded up with the design team at Salesforce and after some back and forth this is what they came up with:

An even simpler logo (added Feb 8):
[image]

The first try:
[image: new Salesforce Stack Exchange logo]

I think it maintains much of the charm of the current logo, but lends some autonomy to this community (and satisfies the intellectual property team at Salesforce).

Here's the full-page mockup of the even simpler logo:

[image]

[Paweł](http://stackexchange.com/users/1170606/pawe%C5%82) took lead on designing this. Curious what you think!

Comment: Looks good. Does it scale nicely as a favicon?
It does remind me that (other than the Salesforce cloud), [There is only one Cloud Icon in the Entire Universe](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThereIsOnlyOneCloudIconInTheEntireUniverse.aspx)

Comment: I much prefer the current branding.

Comment: I like it. Can you make it dynamic so that it shows the weather in your current location? :P

Comment: Maybe the left part of the cloud could pop out a little bit more? Otherwise I like it!

Comment: This looks great !!

Comment: @DanielBallinger - it scales good enough i'd say: http://cl.ly/2k1Y261z0Q0n . Those lines going through cloud are basically invisible but three dots and general shape is just fine.  I could make lines thicker to make them at least slightly visible in 16px size but there would still be some ugly subpixels that I try to avoid. and in normal size I think it looks much better with thinner lines.

Comment: I like it. Can you make it with white and sky blue colors. :P

Comment: Looks good, you made it very simple! May be it look better with sharper arc edges of cloud?

Comment: I don't know about the vertices forming an upside down triangle. I like it better if a couple of the lines are skew. It makes it seem more network-y.

Comment: Personally I don't think you need to draw a cloud just because it's a cloud platform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is getting pushed to production right this minute:

[image: Nodes]

Congrats on your new logo!

Comment: Just noticed it. It looks great. Looking along the tabs in my browser I find it easier to distinguish the SFSE tabs from Salesforce tabs, which will be a plus.

Comment: That's great to hear @DanielBallinger. Who ever knew legal teams could be good for UX.

Comment: The browser tab icon actually looks particularly good - distinctive and clear. Alas, what am I going to do with my old SFSE t-shirt??

Comment: Nice work. FYI you missed the chat favicon. Unless mine is cached...

Comment: @samthebrand can you apply this to our chat too ?  see: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/how-to-fix-chat-favicons

Answer (score 15):

Since you've "simplified" the cloud, I'd like to see you "simplify" the network lines in it at the same time. I feel as though there are too many which makes it busy (I felt the same about the origianl). In my opinion, all lines should pass thru the nodes (larger circles) as would be expected in a network.

Below is a quickly edited example of what I speak of. It isn't meant to suggest "this is exactly how it should appear", only that I'd like to see it appear simpler or "less crowded", having fewer lines as shown in this example.

[image: simplified logo design]

This artwork clearly needs cleaned up, but it's all I had time to do instead of getting out Illustrator to recreate your design to get straight lines and smooth edges. Thank you for your efforts in working through this issue with Salesforce.

Comment: I think I agree with this. Just a few lines clearly indicates a cloud.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. It will also work better when scaled for use as a favicon if it has fewer lines.

Comment: Hey, here's the guy working on logo update. Thanks for this feedback! I'll take it for a ride and try to simplify it a little :)

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could be of service.

Comment: Looks great simplified! Great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the key components that makes the design compelling is that the nodes seem to "refract" the lines that pass through them. If all the lines go straight through the nodes, the whole thing falls flat.