# How to fix Chat Favicons?

Tags: bug, chat

We recently [introduced a new logo](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/a-new-logo-for-salesforce-stack-exchange-revised-version). However, our chat is stuck in the stone ages.

[image: Chat Room Screenshot]

How do we get the chat icons/favicon updated?

Comment: Apparently it's a matter of cache. It can take up to couple days to refresh it. (for me, it's working at the moment, although, logo in header is wrong, so still need to fix it)