# Why bronze cloud looks like piece of sh*t?

Tags: discussion

This is mainly about badges design in salesforce stackexchange.

Other stackexchange communities uses disc as as a badge - which looks ok even if it has bronze color. But, salesforce community uses clouds instead and bronze badges looks quite ridiculous.

See

[image]

Comment: Yea, it ruins my day each time I see it.

Comment: This question belongs in meta. I have flagged this question for moderator attention.

Comment: I personally don't give a ☁. There were [historic reasons](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2091/102) behind current branding. Basically it came down to not being able to use the Salesforce cloud shape and there being [only one other Cloud Icon in the Entire Universe](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThereIsOnlyOneCloudIconInTheEntireUniverse.aspx)

Comment: Upvoted because this thread is really funny. We are lucky that she shit didn't hit the fan

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick it supposed to be funny, but there are too many hypocrite people who pretend to not seeing obvious similarity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no bronze cloud (piece of brown sh*t) anymore - it is just a circle. It is medal now!

Answer (score 16):

It only looks like shit if you are likely to be thinking about shit. If you're thinking about clouds, it looks like a cloud.

Comment: Samuel, I tried to think about clouds before coming back to stackexchange today and it helped. I am going to try the same therapy tomorrow to check if my mental disease gone.